# Aligning input fields using bootstrap css/ css/html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to align the following:

```
<div class="span5">
                    <div class="">
                        <span class="label">Label1</span>
                        <input type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="0">
                    </div>
                    <div class="">   
                        <span class="label">Label2</span>
                        <input type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="0" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="">   
                        <label class="checkbox inline">
                        <input type="checkbox"><span>Something</span>
                        </label> 
                        <input type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="0">
                    </div>       
                    <div class="">     
                        <span class="label">Label4</span>  
                        <input type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="0">
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                        <span class="label label-inverse">Label5</span>
                        <input type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="0">  
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here's the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/qP46X/1267/

I tried margin right but it didnt help. I am not sure how to align the textboxes together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a set width for the `.label` elements.  Ideally you'd have consistency in the layout and you could also use labels for all of the text, but a set width + `display: inline-block` will work.  You can of course change the width as needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/qP46X/1268/

Answer (score 2):

you can also use twitter bootstrap `form-horizontal` css class and its sub-component classes to fulfill your requirement. i modified a bit styling of your code but you might achieve exactly what you want from the below reference( see **Horizontal form** in the below link)

**Reference**: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/qP46X/1269/

Comment: This aligns the labels to the right, but I'm fairly certain he wants them aligned to the left

Comment: yeah it does aligns them to the right. But i wasnt going with the concern for aligning his labels right/left. I just gave him an idea to use the already build bootstrap css classes inorder to achieve proper alignment. He also didnt mentioned whether he wants his label left/right aligned. No objection with your comment though, aligning to the left that's what we generally do. :)